# Using :contains and removeClass together in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, contains, removeclass

I have a question, which I thought I would solve it by myself, but somehow, I could not. I am using `jQuery` to check whether the class single-page `contains` a plus or a minus. If there is a plus, I want the `icon1` to be **green**. If there is a `minus`, I want it to be **red.**

```
<div class="blocking single-page">
 <div class="thumbs-for-you">
  <span class="icon1"></span> 
  <span class="icon2"></span>
 </div>
 <span class="rate">-100</span>
</div>
```

What I tried is (this is just one of the dozen things I tried):

```
$('.single-page:contains("-")').removeClass('.icon2'); 
$('.single-page:contains("-")').removeClass('icon2');
```

I did not got it to work. I also tried using `children` and `siblings`, but with no effect. I am guessing that there is no way to use `removeClass` and `contains` together. Am I wrong or not?

Can somone help me out solving this issue please?

**PS: a little description --> if I remove the classes icon1 and 2, the images will be automatically gone.**

Comment: Try `.removeClass('icon2')` instead `.removeClass('.icon2');`

Comment: As Dado Jerry says, the `.<something>Class()` methods take classes, *not* selectors, so no need for the prefix `.`

Comment: Nope nope and nope. It won't work. I tried that one earlier.

Comment: Well, what we say is true and is a problem with what you've written.  You just have an additional problem too.

Comment: Nope. It was not the correct answer; you just assumed it was correct.

Comment: @Johan: I did not say it was the correct answer - I just said it was a fault with what you had there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes are on your span so you need to traverse to the span that contains that class - also remove the `.` inside removeClass

```
$('.single-page:contains("-") .icon2').removeClass('icon2');
```

or

```
$('.single-page:contains("-")').find('.icon2').removeClass('icon2');
```

Comment: @Johan Glad it helped :)  You were selecting only the div - which doesn't have the class you wanted to remove - so the solution is to get to the element you want so you can modify it

Comment: That's correct. I can't believe I did not see that. Anyhow, thanks again, I owe you one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

You are applying wrong syntax.

*Try to do following*

`.removeClass('icon2');` instead

```
.removeClass('.icon2');
```

Read API [**removeClass**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are applying filter on the element whereas the element you want to select is it's children. Try this.

```
$('.single-page').find(':contains("-")').removeClass('icon2');
```

Here a sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/7Vzs5/

PS. In the sample code you are providing, There isn't even 1 element available which have class `icon2` and contains "-"

Answer (score 0):

The $('.single-page :contains("-")') selector takes you to the div that contains the "-", in this case, the rate div, not the single-page div. Now, you have to back up one level, then find the span.

Always take note of what a selector returns, might help you in the future.

```
$('.single-page :contains("-")').parent().find('span').removeClass('icon2');
```